# Visual Studio Code freezing when second screen is put as primary display on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04, bug-reporting, visual-studio-code

When I set the primary display to the second screen, VS Code start to freezing on that screen but not on the built-in display, when I change the primary display to the built-in display, the VS Code stops freezing on the second screen.

I'm using fresh Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the updated version of VS Code, follow system information:

```
system:
  Host: bernardo-nitro Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.2 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Nitro AN515-44 v: V1.04
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: RO model: Stonic_RNS v: V1.04 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Insyde v: 1.04 date: 02/04/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 42.4 Wh (100.0%) condition: 42.4/58.8 Wh (72.1%)
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1485 min/max: 1400/2900 cores: 1: 1467 2: 1397 3: 1396
    4: 1397 5: 1397 6: 1396 7: 1594 8: 1721 9: 1745 10: 1556 11: 1397 12: 1397
    13: 1431 14: 1649 15: 1434 16: 1397
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia
    v: 515.65.01
  Device-2: AMD Renoir driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,radeon,vesa
    gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1: 2560x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (LLVM 13.0.1 DRM 3.42 5.15.0-46-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor driver: N/A
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek driver: r8169
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: e4:a8:df:f3:72:1d
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: 84:1b:77:29:a2:7a
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX200 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 84:1B:77:29:A2:7E bt-v: 3.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.38 TiB used: 26.41 GiB (1.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital
    model: PC SN530 SDBPNPZ-512G-1014 size: 476.94 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10SPZX-21Z10T0
    size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 245.53 GiB used: 26.35 GiB (10.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 57.2 MiB (59.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: N/A mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 42.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 409 Uptime: 28m Memory: 15 GiB used: 4.32 GiB (28.8%) Shell: Zsh
  inxi: 3.3.13
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was resolved after I updated VS Code to the recent version (1.76)